# How to put space between 2 select fields using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a form but the spacing between the 2 select fields are causing issues. I want the start time , start time meridian, end time , end time meridian in a single line.
Any help??
Thanks in advance.

My html code is:

```
<div class="lable_time">
             <div class="stime">                  
                    <select  value="Start-Time">
                        <option selected  value="null">Start-Time*</option>
                        <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
                        <option value="2:00">2:00</option>

                    </select>

             </div>

             <div class="stime_meridian">
                    <select  value="AM-PM">
                        <option selected  value="null">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
             </div>


              <div class="time">                  
                    <select  value="End-Time">
                        <option selected  value="null">End-Time*</option>
                        <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
                        <option value="2:00">2:00</option>

                    </select>

             </div>

             <div class="time_meridian">
                    <select  value="AM-PM">
                        <option selected  value="null">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
             </div>

        </div>
```

My css:

```
.lable_time select{

    padding: 15px 30px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    width:50%;

    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    color:#5585C8;
     background: white;
     border: 1px solid #2744B8;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 18px;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     outline:none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     border-width:0px;

}


.stime{

    float: left;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 350px;

}

.stime_meridian{

    float: left;
    margin: 30px 10px 0px -170px;
    width: 220px;
    border-spacing: 30px 10px;
}
.time{

    float: left;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px -170px;
    width: 350px;


}

.time_meridian{

    float: left;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px -170px;
    width: 220px;

}
```

Comment: They are in a single line if the viewport width accommodates the widths you've specified... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evRwVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link below where I have edited the code:

```css
.lable_time div{
  display:inline-block;
  width:auto;
}
.lable_time select{

    padding: 15px 30px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    color:#5585C8;
     background: white;
     border: 1px solid #2744B8;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 18px;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
     outline:none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     border-width:0px;

}

.stime{    }

.stime_meridian{    }

.time{    }

.time_meridian{    }
```

```html
<div class="lable_time">
             <div class="stime">                  
                    <select  value="Start-Time">
                        <option selected  value="null">Start-Time*</option>
                        <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
                        <option value="2:00">2:00</option>

                    </select>

             </div>

             <div class="stime_meridian">
                    <select  value="AM-PM">
                        <option selected  value="null">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
             </div>


              <div class="time">                  
                    <select  value="End-Time">
                        <option selected  value="null">End-Time*</option>
                        <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
                        <option value="2:00">2:00</option>

                    </select>

             </div>

             <div class="time_meridian">
                    <select  value="AM-PM">
                        <option selected  value="null">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
             </div>

        </div>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

They are in a single line if the viewport width accommodates the widths you've specified. But if you always want them to be on a single line, you can apply `display: flex` to the parent, and that will put them in a row regardless the viewport width.

```css
.lable_time select {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 50%;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  color: #5585C8;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #2744B8;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-width: 0px;
}

.stime {
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 350px;
}

.stime_meridian {
  margin: 30px 10px 0px -170px;
  width: 220px;
  border-spacing: 30px 10px;
}

.time {
  margin: 30px 0px 0px -170px;
  width: 350px;
}

.time_meridian {
  margin: 30px 0px 0px -170px;
  width: 220px;
}
.lable_time {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="lable_time">
  <div class="stime">
    <select value="Start-Time">
                        <option selected  value="null">Start-Time*</option>
                        <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
                        <option value="2:00">2:00</option>

                    </select>

  </div>

  <div class="stime_meridian">
    <select value="AM-PM">
                        <option selected  value="null">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="time">
    <select value="End-Time">
                        <option selected  value="null">End-Time*</option>
                        <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
                        <option value="2:00">2:00</option>

                    </select>

  </div>

  <div class="time_meridian">
    <select value="AM-PM">
                        <option selected  value="null">AM</option>
                        <option value="PM">PM</option>
                    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```